# Can't connect to websocket server after pushing to vercel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

When ever I run my server locally it works perfectly
But once I upload it to vercel I get errors like polling-xhr.js:202 GET https://giphy-chat-server.vercel.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NQ03j3c&sid=H_PHDh9-4UKRVGTVAAAC 400
And WebSocket connection to 'wss://giphy-chat-server.vercel.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=k-Sex1ZKmrQQFoSKAAAA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
I have tried so many solutions but none is working... I can't just figure out the problem. I would be glad if Its answered. Thank you

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const path = require("path");
var server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    credentials: true,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});
const { MONGODB_URI } = require("./config");
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const Message = require("./message_model");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then((result) => {
    server.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "client", "build")));
const users = [];
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  users.push({ id: socket.id });
  io.emit("users", { users: users });
  Message.find()
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .limit(10)
    .exec((err, messages) => {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      socket.emit("init", messages);
    });
  socket.on("message", (msg) => {
    const message = new Message({
      content: msg.content,
      name: msg.name,
    });
    message.save((err) => {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
    });
    socket.broadcast.emit("push", msg);
  });
  socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
    let index = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      const user = users[i];
      if (user.id === socket.id) {
        index = i;
      }
    }
    if (index !== -1) {
      users.splice(index, 1);
    }
    io.emit("users", { users: users });
  });
});
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Giphy Chat Server is running successfully");
});
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this will be due to Vercel's serverless functions having a maximum execution timeout, so they can't maintain a websocket connection. In order to use Websockets with Vercel you'll need to use a third party service to handle your websocket connections for you. Something like Ably or Pusher, or PubNub.

I just wrote up a demo of next + ably if it would be helpful - https://github.com/ably-labs/NextJS-chat-app

Comment: Thanks alot
I found that out after days of research
I had to push to heroku and it worked just fine

Comment: Found the article on Vercel's official website: https://vercel.com/support/articles/do-vercel-serverless-functions-support-websocket-connections
just in case someone is still looking for their official confirmation