# Pusher working only after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, next.js, pusher, vercel

I'm implementing pusher in a web application using nextjs. It works as expected in my development environment. But it does not work correctly when I deploy it to vercel. I can only see the results when I refresh the page in the browser.

This is the implementation for the client:

```
useEffect(() => {

    const pusher = new Pusher(`${process.env.PUSHER_KEY}`, {
        cluster: `${process.env.PUSHER_CLUSTER}`,
        useTLS: true
    });

    const channel = pusher.subscribe('franks-auto-spa');
    channel.bind('cancel-wash', data => {
        console.log(data.date);
        removeWash(data.date);
    });

}, []);
```

And this is the implementation for the API:

```
export default async (req, res) => {

    const connection = await mysql.createConnection(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
    console.log(req.body.date);
    const result = await connection.query('DELETE FROM ongoing WHERE date = ?', [req.body.date]);
    console.log(result);

    const pusher = new Pusher({
        appId: `${process.env.PUSHER_ID}`,
        key: `${process.env.PUSHER_KEY}`,
        secret: `${process.env.PUSHER_SECRET}`,
        cluster: `${process.env.PUSHER_CLUSTER}`,
        useTLS: true
    });

    pusher.trigger('franks-auto-spa', 'cancel-wash', req.body);
    res.json({message: 'Wash deleted deleted...'});
}
```

Am I missing any configuration in Vercel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem too, once or twice; Vercel times out after a little bit. (10 seconds on Hobby) So using a database with Vercel probably isn't gonna fly. Have you tried switching to the Pro plan? Or you could switch to [Heroku](https://heroku.com), which not only has a longer timeout (30 seconds), but also [supports websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65688135/15778548).

Comment: Thank u. The issue was with Vercel actually

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry for late reply. I just found out too. Just add await to prevent serverless features from being turned off!

```js
pusher.trigger('franks-auto-spa', 'cancel-wash', req.body);
```

to

```js
await pusher.trigger('franks-auto-spa', 'cancel-wash', req.body);
```

Answer (score 1):

To those experiencing the same problem, awaiting the **pusher.trigger()** method solves the issue.

```
await pusher.trigger("channel-id", "incoming-message", "your-message")
```